# sed - range match - one side of the range is a multiline pattern

Tags: awk, sed, pattern-matching, range

First time caller...  Longtime reader.

Here is an example of the input that I am working with.

```
.
.
.
exit
exit
set vsys "dr-site"
set vsys-id 2
set vrouter "dr-site-vr"
unset auto-route-export
exit
set service "service1"
set service "service2"
set zone id 101 "Trust1"
set zone id 201 "Untrust1"
set zone id 301 "DMZ1"
set interface "ethernet3/1.3"
set interface "ethernet3/1.4"
set interface "ethernet3/1.6"
set route 0.0.0.0/0
set address "Untrust1"
set address "Trust1"
set address "DMZ1"
set group address "Untrust1"
set group address "Trust1"
set group address "DMZ1"
set group service
set policy id 100
exit
set policy id 200
exit
set policy id 300
exit
set policy id 400
exit
exit
set vsys "datacenter"
set vsys-id 1
set vrouter "datacenter-vr"
unset auto-route-export
exit
set service "service1"
set service "service2"
set zone id 100 "Trust"
set zone id 200 "Untrust"
set zone id 300 "DMZ"
set interface "ethernet3/1.5"
set interface "ethernet3/1.2"
set interface "ethernet3/1.1"
set route 0.0.0.0/0
set address "Untrust"
set address "Trust"
set address "DMZ"
set group address "Untrust"
set group address "Trust"
set group address "DMZ"
set group service
set policy id 100
exit
set policy id 200
exit
set policy id 300
exit
set policy id 400
exit
exit
set vsys "other"
.
.
.
```

I need to start my range at `set vsys "datacenter"` (for example) and stop when I see (2) consecutive `exit`.

Usually, I just:

```
gsed -n '/set vsys "datacenter"/,/exit/p; file
```

But I need pattern #2 to catch (2) consecutive exit:

```
gsed -n '/set vsys "datacenter"/,/exit\nexit/p; file
```

Thus my range match has a multiline pattern for range #2.

I've tried using the sed N command but I'm not doing something right.  I will also use this sed command to parse out the vsys sections as needed and these sections always end with (2) consecutive `exit`.

As requested, the expected output should look like this:

```
set vsys "datacenter"
set vsys-id 1
set vrouter "datacenter-vr"
unset auto-route-export
exit
set service "service1"
set service "service2"
set zone id 100 "Trust"
set zone id 200 "Untrust"
set zone id 300 "DMZ"
set interface "ethernet3/1.5"
set interface "ethernet3/1.2"
set interface "ethernet3/1.1"
set route 0.0.0.0/0
set address "Untrust"
set address "Trust"
set address "DMZ"
set group address "Untrust"
set group address "Trust"
set group address "DMZ"
set group service
set policy id 100
exit
set policy id 200
exit
set policy id 300
exit
set policy id 400
exit
exit
```

Comment: Show the expected output given that input. sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines - the simplest solution to this problem will be in awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using sed:

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/.*(set vsys "datacenter".*exit\nexit).*/\1/' file
```

For BSD sed, try replacing `-r` with `-E`.

#### How it works

- `H;1h;$!d;x;`

  This is a sed idiom for reading the whole file in at once.  If the file is huge, the use a different solution, such as the awk solution below.
- `s/.*(set vsys "datacenter".*exit\nexit).*/\1/`

  This extracts the part that we want.

### Using awk

```
awk '/set vsys "datacenter"/{f=1;} f{print;} /exit/ && last {exit;} {last=0;} f && /exit/{last=1;}' file
```

#### How it works

- `/set vsys "datacenter"/{f=1;}`

  When we see the start line, set flag `f` to true (1).
- `f{print}`

  If flag `f` is true print the line
- `/exit/ && last {exit;}`

  If this line contains `exit` and the previous line also contained `exit`, then we are done and we tell awk to `exit`.
- `{last=0}`

  Set last to false (0).
- `f && /exit/{last=1}`

  This prepares for the next line.  If flag `f` is true and this line contains `exit`, then set last to true (1).

### Using python3

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
f = False
last = False
with open('file', 'r') as fhandle:
    for line in fhandle:
        if 'set vsys "datacenter"' in line:
            f = True
        if f:
            print(line, end="")
        if last and 'exit' in line:
            break
        last = False
        if f and 'exit' in line:
            last = True
```

The logic here is basically the same as for the awk solution.

Comment: Thanks for adding sed with explanations along with awk and explanations.  Both your sed and awk worked as required.  I wish there was a "prettier" way of doing it in sed.  I guess I should look into Perl or Python once I start working with multiple lines.  =_)

Comment: @menesesinc For comparison, I added a python solution.

Comment: As I am working with 32 of these "vsys", the first one worked using your gsed script but to be fair it was the last vsys in the configuration.  Today, I had to move on to another vsys within the same large file and the gsed script is catching, using my original example, set vsys "dr-site" and everything in between, passing its exit\nexit, then catching set vsys "datacenter" and everything in between and then finally ending with that vsys' exit\nexit.  Your awk script though is working on both cases flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Untested since you didn't provide expected output but you need something like this:

```
awk '
/set vsys "datacenter"/{ f=1; rec=prev="" }
f {
    rec=rec $0 ORS
    if ( /exit/ && (prev==$0) ) {
        printf "%s", rec
        f=0
    }
    prev = $0
}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/set vsys "datacenter"/!d;:a;N;/exit\s*\nexit\s*$/!ba' file
```

If a line doesn't contain the required string delete it. If it does, append the following line and check for the double `exit` condition and if not found continue appending lines until the condition is met. Print out the lines held in the pattern space.

Comment: This was also very helpful.  Thanks for adding your comment.